# Model uncertainty quantification

Tags: bayesian, mutual-information, uncertainty, entropy

I'm reading a paper about model uncertainty quantification. Specifically, it says epistemic uncertainty is a kind of uncertainty due to lack of knowledge about a particular region in the input space.

Also, it makes a mathematical characterization of uncertainty. Denoting $x$ and $y$ the input and output points, and $\cal{D}$ the training data, the total uncertainty $\cal{U}$ of a model with respect to the input $x$ can be measured by the predictive entropy:

${\cal U}(x)={\cal H}( P(y|x,{\cal D}))=-\sum_y P(y|x,{\cal D})\log P(y|x,\cal{D})$

Denoting $P(\theta | \cal D)$ the posterior distribution over the model parameters $\theta$, it also decomposes the uncertainty $\cal U$ in other two terms:

${\cal U}(x)=({\cal H}( P(y|x,{\cal D})) -\mathbb{E}_{P(\theta|{\cal D})}[{\cal H}(P(y|x,\theta)]) + \mathbb{E}_{P(\theta|\cal D)}[{{\cal H}(P(y|x,\theta)}]$

My question is, why the first term, as it calls mutual information between $\theta$ and $y$, is capable of expressing the epistemic uncertainty?

[reference](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2021/hash/06fe1c234519f6812fc4c1baae25d6af-Abstract.html)

Comment: Would probably be helpful if you could reference the paper

Comment: The first term, which refers to the mutual information between $\theta$ and $y$, expresses epistemic uncertainty by comparing the entropy of the distribution $P(y|x,\theta)$ with the expected entropy $E_{P(\theta|D)}[H(P(y|x,\theta))]$, where $D$ is the dataset used to train the model. Since fixing a set of weights $w$ removes the epistemic uncertainty, this term can be used to quantify it.

Comment: @Multivac Why fixing a set of weights $w$ removes epistemic uncertainty?

Comment: Fixing a set of weights removes epistemic uncertainty because considering a distribution $p(y | \vec{w}, \vec{x})$, or in other words, fixing a set of weights, makes the epistemic uncertainty $u_e=0$. Epistemic uncertainty is a lack of knowledge about a particular region in the input space.

Comment: According to the paper you are reading, considering a distribution $p(y | \vec{w}, \vec{x})$, or in other words, fixing a set of weights, removes the epistemic uncertainty. Epistemic uncertainty is defined as a lack of knowledge about a particular region in the input space. Denoting $x$ and $y$ the input and output points, and $\cal{D}$ the training data, the total uncertainty $\cal{U}$ of a model with respect to the input $x$ can be measured by the predictive entropy:
${\cal U}(x)={\cal H}( P(y|x,{\cal D}))=-\sum_y P(y|x,{\cal D})\log P(y|x,\cal{D})$

Comment: The author suggests that fixing weights removes epistemic uncertainty as it considers the knowledge conveyed by the distribution $p(y | \vec{w}, \vec{x})$ which "weakens" the knowledge.